# How to come up with this percent error with Rectangular integration method

Tags: c++, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I'm reviewing some numerical methods for integration. I came across Rectangular integration method (i.e. Euler's method). According to the book I'm reading, the actual algorithm is

[image]

The code is self-explanatory. The author provides this example `dxdt=cos(t)` with an initial value `x(0)=0`. The analytical solution is `x=sin(t)`. We can compute the error at `t=1` and indeed the author provides it in the following table:

[image]

The problem is that in my following code, the error is 9.1% but in the preceding table, the error actually is 2.6. Did I make a mistake?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    double x(0.0), dxdt, t(0.0), T(0.1), stopTime(1.0);

    for ( ; t <= stopTime; t += T ){
        dxdt = cos(t);
          x += dxdt*T;

          if ( t > 0.9 )
            std::cout << "Time: " << t << "  Error: " << fabs( (x - sin(t)) /sin(t) )*100.0 <<  std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take into account that while `x` is updated to an approximation of `x(t+T)`, the loop variable `t` will only be incremented at the very end of the loop, so retains it value `t` during the output. This time mismatch introduces an additional relative error of `abs(sin(t+T)/sin(t)-1)` which for `t=1, T=0.1` is about `5.91 %`.

You should also make the loop stable under rounding errors in the `t` incrementation, either by computing the exact number of loops or by choosing bounds in the inequality that are in-between the steps as in

```
while ( t < stopTime-0.5*T ){
    dxdt = cos(t);
      x += dxdt*T;
      t += T;

    if ( t > stopTime -2.5*T )
        std::cout << "Time: " << t << "  Error: " << fabs( (x - sin(t)) /sin(t) )*100.0 <<  std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.